# php Function for Getting Information from Address Bar and Including a Specified File (Dynamic Pages?)

Tags: php

I'm new to stackoverflow and to php and I'm trying to code this right. What I am trying to do is eliminate the display of pages other than index.php but still include them by utilizing the address bar. For example, I'm trying to write a login script that includes a login.php file but handles all of the form's post information and checks through the index.php file.

I'm trying to create a function to include only specific pages when called upon by the address bar. So the form's action would be to index.php?act=login - I want to $_GET the act (login) and include login.php without the ability for users to include any other files that pose a security risk.

This is my code:

```
    function getContent() {

    $pages = array('login','page1');

    if(isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act'] == $pages) {
        include($_GET['act'] . '.php');
    } elseif (!isset($_GET['act'])) {
        echo 'INDEX PAGE';
    }
}

getContent();
```

Where am I going wrong? I can't get the login.php page to display when index.php?act=login is set. The text "INDEX PAGE" displays just fine with act is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is your problem:

```
 if(isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act'] == $pages) {
```

You need to change it to this (as you're checking if the value of `act` exists in the array of pages):

```
if(isset($_GET['act']) && in_array($_GET['act'], $pages)) {
```

You might want to replace your `elseif` with a standard else, though. Because if `$_GET['act']` is set, but isn't in the array of pages, your elseif won't be executed.

Furthermore, I'd strongly recommend you using a micro-framework like [Limonade](http://www.limonade-php.net/), which will handle this for you (much more safely), once you feel more familiar with PHP.

Comment: I've been told that frameworks are good, but for starting out it's better to write your own code. Is a micro framework any better than a full framework (was looking at Cake PHP).

Comment: You're right, definitely (edited to reflect that). Micro-frameworks vs. full-stack frameworks are another question entirely, but they're both better for different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this to in_array():

```
if(isset($_GET['act']) && in_array($_GET['act'], $pages)) {
    include('path-to-file/'.$_GET['act'] . '.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` is incorrect. You want something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['act']) && in_array($_GET['act'], $pages)) {
    include($_GET['act'] . '.php');
}
```